# Removing NA columns in xts

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I have an xts in the following format

```
                   a        b     c        d       e        f   ......
2011-01-03         11.40    NA    23.12    0.23    123.11   NA  ......
2011-01-04         11.49    NA    23.15    1.11    111.11   NA  ......
2011-01-05         NA       NA    23.11    1.23    142.32   NA  ......
2011-01-06         11.64    NA    39.01    NA      124.21   NA  ......
2011-01-07         13.84    NA    12.12    1.53    152.12   NA  ......
```

Is there a function I can apply to generate a new xts or data.frame missing the columns containing only NA?

The position of the columns with the NAs isn't static so just removing those columns by name or position isn't possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supose `DF` is your data.frame

```
 DF [, -which(sapply(DF, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))==nrow(DF))]
               a     c    d      e
2011-01-03 11.40 23.12 0.23 123.11
2011-01-04 11.49 23.15 1.11 111.11
2011-01-05    NA 23.11 1.23 142.32
2011-01-06 11.64 39.01   NA 124.21
2011-01-07 13.84 12.12 1.53 152.12
```

Comment: A more robust solution would be: `DF[, sapply(DF, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))!=nrow(DF)]` because it would work even if there are no columns with all missing values (see my answer).

Answer (score 5):

[@Jiber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315767/jilber)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13099010/271616) works, but might give you unexpected results if there are no columns with all `NA`.  For example:

```
# sample data
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

# Jiber's solution, when no columns have all missing values
DF <- as.data.frame(x)
DF[, -which(sapply(DF, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))==nrow(DF))]
# data frame with 0 columns and 180 rows
```

Here's a solution that works whether or not there are columns that have all missing values:

```
y <- x[,apply(!is.na(x), 2, all)]
x$High <- NA
x$Close <- NA
z <- x[,apply(!is.na(x), 2, all)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dataframe[,-which(apply(is.na(dataframe), 2, all))]
```

Comment: And if I don't know which columns contain the NAs?

Comment: this takes into account any given data frame without knowing the NA's ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

This seems simpler:

```
DF[, colSums(is.na(DF)) < nrow(DF)]
```

Comment: It should be either `DF[, !colSums(!is.na(DF)) < nrow(DF)]` or `DF[, !colSums(is.na(DF)) > 0]` to work...